# Error: Failed to lookup view "home.hbs" in views directory

Tags: javascript, express, express-handlebars

I am implementing a web app with a **three layered architecture**. Now I am trying to render a file in my **views** folder. This is my folder structure and the code:

[image]

But when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "home.hbs" in views directory "/web-app/pl/views"
```

Any suggestions how to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

> Your bug is in this code `app.set('views', path.join("/web-app/pl", "views"));` make sure to remove `/` in your `/web-app`. So its will looks like this `app.set('views', path.join("web-app/pl", "views"));`

‍ Make sure to create a folder in your root app: `web-app/pl/views` And put your `home.hbs` in your `views` folder.

**So** your folder will looks like this:

```
- public
- node-modules
- src > server.js
- web-app > pl > views > home.hbs // if set in render { layout: false }
- web-app > pl > views > layouts > main.hbs // default layout
```

‍ **For an example**, your `app` will looks like this code below:

```js
const express = require('express');
const expressHandlebars = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join("web-app/pl", "views"));
app.engine("hbs", expressHandlebars({
  defaultLayout: "main.hbs"
}))

app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('home', {
    layout: false
  })
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is up');
})
```

**For an example** you can see in my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-darkness-73opp

I hope it can help you .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried this but it does not work. However when I move the views folder into the src folder, then it works?

Comment: Why you can say it's not woking? It's working fine, if you're using that code above. For an example you can see it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-darkness-73opp

Comment: But you're right, it's not working, if you're not set: `{ layout: false }` in render method like as what I do in my code above.

Comment: I have the exact same code as you but I have a different structure in my folders. I have my src folder inside the web-app folder and the web-app folder is inside the blogzoApp folder as shown in my picture above.